# HTML5 Database GUI

Tags: database, html, user-interface, interface

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a front-end GUI for an HTML5 database?  I'm working on a web-app and having to debug the database with no GUI is tough sometime.  Is there any kind of phpMyAdmin project for an HTML5 Database?

Comment: Actually, I think I just discovered the answer - Chrome's debugger (F12) has a "Databases" element under "Resources".   It doesn't seem like you can query it, but it's good enough.

I'll leave this question open in case someone has a better answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and Safari both have a database GUI and a command-line interface. As you've discovered, they are under the 'Resources > Databases' tab of the Developer Tools (its called the Web Inspector in Safari). Both are very similar, given that both browsers are based on Webkit.

You can get the command line interface for ad-hoc queries by selecting the name of your database. You will have had to of called `openDatabase()` in the console or in your code before being able to see your database.

The database is based on SQLite, so you will be able to use almost every command that SQLite accepts here, except the helper commands, such as '.tables', etc.

Also keep in mind that the GUI won't let you add or delete databases, but will let you inspect the contents of your table. You can delete tables by calling the Drop function from the command line. It also won't let it add/edit/remove rows directly, you'll still need to use insert/update/delete queries for that too.